# Interaction with parent control triggers RippleDrawable in Xamarin.Forns custom renderer

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have implemented a custom clickable label class in Xamarin.Forms along with a custom renderer, that adds a `RippleDrawable` as the controls `Foreground`. I am creating the `RippleDrawable` with the following code:

```
public static Drawable CreateRippleDrawable(Context context)
{
    var typedValue = new TypedValue();
    context.Theme.ResolveAttribute(Resource.Attribute.SelectableItemBackground, typedValue, true);
    var rippleDrawable = context.Resources.GetDrawable(typedValue.ResourceId, context.Theme);
    return rippleDrawable;
}
```

In my custom renderer I assign the drawable

```
this.Control.Foreground = DrawableHelper.CreateRippleDrawable(this.Context);
```

and update the ripple when the user touches the control

```
private void LinkLabelRenderer_Touch(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
    {
        this.Pressed = true;
    }

    if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Cancel)
    {
        this.Pressed = false;
    }

    if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
    {
        this.Ripple.SetHotspot(e.Event.GetX(), e.Event.GetY());
        this.Pressed = false;

        // raise the event of the Xamarin.Forms control
    }
}
```

Now, whenever I click the control, the ripple will be shown, which is the expected behavior, but if I touch (tap or long-press) the parents of the control (e.g. the `StackLayout`, `Grid` or whatever layout contains the label, including their parent `Layout`, `Page` or `View`) the ripple animation will be triggered. Anyway, the event handler `LinkLabelRenderer_Touch` in not called in this case, only when the actual control is touched.

I can work around this behavior by adding an empty `GestureRecognizer` to the respective parent(s), but I really dislike this solution, because this is but a hack. And to make things worse it is a hack I'll always have to remember whenever I use the control.

How can I prevent the `RippleDrawable` being shown when the parent is touched?

Comment: Are you planning to support Android API 19 and below?

Comment: Nope, but thank you, I managed to solve it on my own.

Comment: Sure its better if you post it as an answer so other know what you did

Comment: @G.hakim I intended to do so, but did not have the time, yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out I got things fundamentally wrong. Subscribing the `Touch` event is not the way to go. I had to make the control clickable and subscribe the `Click` event

```
this.Control.Clickable = true;
this.Click += LinkLabelRenderer_OnClick;
```

There is no need to handle all that `RippleTouch` stuff the way I did (via the `Touch` event) but could let android handle things for me.